# Why do I keep on getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, http-post

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://wandbox.org/api/compile.json',
  compiler: 'cpython-3.8.0',
  code: 'print("hello")',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}
```

When I have this as "options" and I do:

```
request.post(options, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
                    if (err) {
                      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
                    }
                    console.log(body)
                    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', httpResponse);
                  })
```

the body is nothing and in httpResponse I get

```
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
```

why is that? what is wrong with my request? I am trying to follow https://github.com/melpon/wandbox/blob/master/kennel2/API.rst
but nothing seems to work. How can I fix my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending the parameters as a JSON string as you should.